# Trying to delete values from array which contain "X" string.

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently making a system where users can post things to a table, which automatically adds a "Day-".date("N"); to the string that's posted to the table, and once one week transpires, I will delete it. I've already worked out the logistics of implementing this - that whenever a user adds a post, it checks a day.txt file to see if the day is a different day, and if it is, it runs the following function:

```
// The function is quite simple in theory:
// Load the two lists as a string, convert to array
// Send code out removing all posts with a certain day.
function removeOldPosts(){
    $newday = ':Day-'.date('N');
// I realise the below two lines are unefficient, I'll consolidate them later
    $currentPosts = file_get_contents('list.txt');
    $posts = explode(" ", $currentPosts); 
    while(($key = array_search($newday, $posts)) !== false){
        unset($posts[$key]);
        echo 'Unset a value: '.$key.'<br>';
    }
    echo ($posts); // Testing variables in array
    $newPosts = implode(" ", $posts);
    echo $newPosts;
    file_put_contents('list.txt', $newPosts);
    return;
}
```

However, the "echos" still show up as containing the values that I want to remove... and I'm wondering if anyone spots an error in my code - I'm assuming something's wrong with my while statement, but this is quite literally the first time I'm ever using such a statement, so I'm not entirely sure how to efficiently find all values which contain the current day, and then delete them.

For the "list.txt" contents, it looks like

```
1:Spitfire:Day-4:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:110 1:Spitfire:Day-4:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:110 1:Spitfire:Day-4:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:110 1:Spitfire:Day-4:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:110 1:Spitfire:Day-4:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:1101:Spitfire:Day-4:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:110 1:Spitfire:Day-4:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:110 1:Spitfire:Day-4:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:110
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: You should definitely start learning SQL. That will make your life much easier in the long run.

Comment: True, and I do know some MySQL with php using the Medoo framework - However I'm not the best at it, and since the posts themselves are rather small, I've decided against it - for now anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clean up an array try with [array_filter](https://www.php.net/array_filter). This example will remove all entries with ':Day-4' substring.

```
$currentPosts = '1:Spitfire:Day-4:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:110 1:Spitfire:Day-5:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:110 1:Spitfire:Day-6:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:110 1:Spitfire:Day-3:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:110 1:Spitfire:Day-4:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:110 1:Spitfire:Day-4:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:110 1:Spitfire:Day-5:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:110 1:Spitfire:Day-4:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:110';

$posts = explode( " ", $currentPosts );     
$posts = array_filter( $posts, function( $item ) { 
    return strpos( $item, ':Day-4' ) === false; 
});

print_r( $posts );
```

Comment: In addition to this answer, here's an explanation why your original solution did not work: [`array_search`](http://www.php.net/array_search) will only find entries of an array that match exactly the first passed argument. It won't consider partial matches. Therefore you'll have to implement your filter method on your own - for example like in this answer.

Comment: This works for the most part - except for this error: How come I have to put the ':Day-4' as the second argument in strpos for it to work - when I use my '$newday' variable, even though they print to the exact same thing, it does not work - Which is a problem since I don't fancy creating a new if statement for every day in order to do this - help please?

Comment: Since you've already selected an answer, you'd usually have to open a new question for this variation. (People don't get many points on Stackoverflow for upvoted comments.) But to make it easier for you this time: I think the solution is to simply add `use ($newday)` after `function( $item )`. For more information check this page: http://php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: As @HaukeP. suggested, import variables to a closure's scope with `function( $item ) use ($newday)`, and replace `':Day-4'` to `$newday`. Thanks @HaukeP. for the assistance with this question.